# Joomla: Not displaying any error on login fail 

Tags: joomla2.5

I am using login id and password on Joomla 2.5.
When I am giving wrong password it’s displaying blank page. No error.
Please help what could be the possible error. I am new to Joomla. When I started I also deleted some template styles and modules from admin part. If this is the reason then how could I get those back? I already tried copying and pasting template folder to project.

Comment: @SørenBeckJensen:Thank u very much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the index.php in your template has the following in it:

```
<jdoc:include type="message"/>
```

This is where error messages are displayed.

Also, why would you remove part of the admin templates?